# Process system isn't responding on android device emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm newbie in Android devlopement I installed Android studio configured every thing Android SDK, JDK , System variables .. every thing works just fine until i created my Android Virtual device , first, it takes so long to start , second, after it shows the hello world an error message pops up saying "Process system isn't responsing x Close app , o Wait" 
I tried creating many other devices , with low RAM low resolution , I even changed the config file but none of them works for me I always get the same error .. help please I'm stuck in this for two days.. THANKS [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JTFU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable virtualization from bios of your system.also increase your system RAM.

Comment: Yes but on some systems it is disabled

Comment: I'm pretty sure Android Studio doesn't start an emulator if virtualization isn't enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to get rid of the app not responding close/wait error:

Android Studio --> Help --> Edit VmOptions

As posted above this was a solution to my "Processing system isn't responding".
I used the Nexus S API 23, 4.0 480x800 hdpi
Graphics in Software mode
RAM 2GB VM heap: 48m 
Internal storage 600m
The Processing error does not appear. I do get the Google Play not working, but the background screen updated. After leaving it for almost 30 minutes, it came up. i was able to run my app.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to get rid of the app not responding close/wait error:

Android Studio --> Help --> Edit VmOptions

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I struggled for 3-4 days, and finally managed to resolve this error. Android emulator also works fast, first time boot is always sloow, but subsequent changes in app are faster!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm Shreepal, I tried mine to help. Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

1. List item Make sure you have the latest version of Android Studio installed.
2. List item Ensure that the graphics acceleration is enabled in the BIOS and the emulator configuration.
3. Disable the "Use Host GPU" option in the emulator settings.
4. Use an x86-based system image instead of an arm-based one.
5. Try to run the emulator from the command line using the "emulator" command and see if there are any error messages that can give you a clue about what's going wrong.

If none of these solutions works, you can try to search for specific error messages in the Android Studio log files, or ask for help on online forum.